# How to move unselected items from a List to another? JList

Tags: java, jlist

I'm trying to move only the unselected items from a List into another List. Also I would like to validate if the items are already on the next list before moving them.

This is what I have so far

```
 int sel[] = lstNum1.getSelectedIndices();

    for (int i = 0; i < model1.getSize(); i++) {
        if(!model1.getElementAt(i).equals(model1.getElementAt(sel[i]).toString())){
            model2.addElement(model1.getElementAt(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to compare the item at position "i" with the item at the selectedArray, but no luck.

Comment: so sel[] hold the indices that you do not want to move

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm trying to choose the items I want to copy.

Comment: please look at my answer. i think i have done what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your int[] sel to a Set. this will make it easy to check before adding to new list

```
   Set<Integer> keepThese = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int x : sel)
    {
      keepThese.add(x);
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<firstList.size() ; i++)
    {
       if(keepThese.contains(i))
            continue;

       else
       {
         if(secondList.contains(firstList.get(i)))
           continue;

         else
          secondList.add(firstList.get(i));

       }

  }
```

now secondList will have all the elements from firstList that are not at indices in the sel array

Comment: What is a "set"? and by "firstList.size" you mean the List or the model size?

Comment: You don't need to check if it `contains(i)` calling `add()` will do this already

Comment: set is a collection of elements. in a set there can be no duplicates. i am using a set as it will allow me to utilize the contains method to quickly check if the index that i am looking at should be skipped or not. otherwise i would have to iterate over the sel array for each index of the list that i am trying to copy from

Comment: @3kings, we need to check for two things. first, whether we should skip the current index. second, if the current index is valid, then whether the element at this index is already present in the secondList

Comment: You don't define `secondList` what would that be? also a set?

Comment: i am assuming that is the list that we want as result. i am not sure where that should be defined in the code. depends on @Midori_hige

Comment: sure, feel free to make the change. my code is mean as a template.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get it working now I'm trying to remove the very same items that where moved to Model2. Should I use another for loop for that one?

Comment: which items are you trying to remove from Model2?

Comment: I mean, trying to remove from Model1 (the firstList) the unselected items.

Comment: same process. just the name of the list changes

Comment: How would I do that? I made the same process down bellow the code, inverting the list names, but the moved items were not removed.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of the answer provided by AbtPst:

```
    Set<Integer> keepThese = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : sel) {
      keepThese.add(x);
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<firstList.size() ; i++) {
       if( !keepThese.contains(i)) {
         if( !secondList.contains(firstList.get(i))) {
           secondList.add(firstList.get(i));
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Now, how do I removed the moved items?